# C: Is there anything called a 'prefix expression'?

Tags: c, c11, postfix-operator, prefix-operator

The ISO/IEC 9899:2011 (American National Standard for C11) talks about postfix expressions, but there's nothing called a prefix expression. Why so?

Answer (score 3):

There's a whole syntactic category *postfix expression*, but the prefix operators are classified as unary operators and defined in the syntactic category *unary expression*, which include the prefix increment and decrement operators.  Note that postfix expressions include array subscripting, function calls, and the `.` and `->` operators, not just postfix increment and decrement.

As to why: there is no stated reason — it simply wasn't seen as a necessary name.